# How to refer react to PHP file using fetch and catch

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs

I'm trying to use fetch and catch method to send JSON stringfy request to PHP file I have that execute certain function.

Now I don't receive any error, but I can't get the function to work properly.

```
        fetch('http://localhost/server/mail.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers : { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
               },
            body: JSON.stringify({ // Passes values to mail.php
                name: inputName,
                phone: inputPhone
            }),
        })
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response);
            if(response === 'success'){
                history.push("/start"); // Route to another page
                history.go(0);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) { // Return error
            console.log(err);
        });
```

If I debug `console.log(response)` I receive react object that contains the following:

> Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost/server/mail.php",
> redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, bodyUsed: false, ...}

And lastly, the PHP code that I used PHP Mailer library to send mail through it, I used the same code before in another project, should work fine.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require './phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = 'admin@yotamdahan.com'
$to = 'admin@yotamdahan.com'; 
$message = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = 'משתמש חדש';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host   = "server270.web-hosting.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->Username   = $to;
$mail->Password   = "*******";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->setFrom($from);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "שם השולח: " . $name . "\r\n <br/> הודעה: " . $message;
$mail->addAddress($to, 'Yotam Dahan');

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo "success";
}
```

My problem is that PHP doesn't send the email, I guess that `inputName` and `InputPhone` does not pass correctly so the code doesn't run and the response isn't `success` as it should be.

How can I send proper POST request to PHP via fetch & catch in reactJS?

Comment: Are you missing a port number here -> `'http://localhost/server/mail.php'`?

Comment: If the php files are within the same project structure. It would just be `/mail.php` if you are not seeing it execute. It's because you need a web server which can execute php scripts i.e., Nginx or Apache. Hope that helps

Comment: @PrateekThapa it's running on XAMPP server, so there is no port needed

Comment: @TheoNeUpKID I placed all my files, React and PHP inside XAMPP htdocs folder

Comment: If thats the case then the HTML file would reference resources locally right, so then the fetch would be /mail.php not localhost

Comment: I have tried use './mail.php' directory but it doesn't seems to find it. when I use localhost it works.

Comment: it wouldn't use `./` referenceing it would just be `/mail.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending data as `application/json` but `$_POST` get datas from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You could use `FormData` to create data with the right content-type and then use `URLSearchParams` to pass that `FormData` to the body of your fetch function.

You can use FormData like this :

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("name", inputName);
```

and then send it like this

```js
fetch('http://localhost/server/mail.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  redirect: 'follow',
  body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I just can't get this to work either, I receive the same response, maybe I need to use `response => response.json()` first?